# How to implement synonyms for use in a search engine?

Tags: nlp, full-text-search, artificial-intelligence, text-mining, word2vec

I am working on a pet search engine (SE).

What I have right now is boolean keyword SE, as a library that is split in two parts:

- index: this is a inverted index ie. it associate terms with the original document where it appears
- query: which is supplied by the user and can be arbitrarily complex boolean expression that looks like `(mobile OR android OR iphone) AND game`

I'd like to improve the search engine, in a way that does automatically extend simple queries to boolean queries so that it includes search terms that do no appear in the original query ie. I'd like to support synonyms.

I need some help to build the synonyms graph.

How can I compute list of words that appears in similar context?

Here is example of list of synonyms I'd like to compute:

- psql, pgsql, postgres, postgresql
- mobile, iphone, android

and also synonyms that includes ngrams like:

- rdbms, relational database management systems, ...

The algorithm doesn't have to be perfect, I can post-process by hand the result, but at least I need to have a clue about what terms are similar to what other terms.

Comment: I think what you want to do is called "[probabilistic topic-modeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topic-modeling)", but cannot answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the standard Information Retrieval (IR) literature, this enrichment of a query with additional terms (that don't appear in the initial/original query) is known as **query expansion**.

There're a plenty of standard approaches which, generally speaking, are based on the idea of *scoring* terms based on some factors and then selecting a number of terms (say K, a parameter) that have the highest scores.

To compute the term selection score, it is assumed that the top (M) ranked documents retrieved after initial retrieval are relevant, this being called **pseudo-relevance feedback**.

The factors on which the term selection function generally depend are:

1. The term frequency of a term in a top ranked document - higher the better.
2. The number of documents (out of top M) in which the term occurs in - higher the better.
3. How many times does an additional term *co-occur* with a query term - the higher the better.

The co-occurrence factor is the most important and would be give you terms such as 'pgsql' if the original query contains 'psql'.

Note that if documents are too short, this method would not work well and you have to use other methods that are necessarily semantics based such as i) [word-vector based expansion](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2766462.2767780) or ii) wordnet-based expansion.